# RxJava2 + Retrofit black screen at data request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm facing an issue with an android app while trying to retrieve some Api data using RxJava2 And Retrofit2 (in Kotlin). Once I execute the call, the screen turns black and the application just doesn't respond anymore, without any log messages.

The call URL I'm using is the following:

```
api/apartments?projection={"id":1,"address":1}
```

The Service interface for this call is this one:

```
    @GET("api/apartments?projection={\"id\":1,\"address\":1}")
    fun getAllApartments(@Header(AUTHORIZATION) auth: String): Single<List<APTLIST>>
```

This is the way I execute the call:

```
  override fun getAllApartments(): Single<List<APTLIST>> = retrofit.create(ApartmentsService::class.java).getAllApartments("$BEARER$token")
```

And this is how I call the function:

```
getAllApartmentsUseCase.getAllApartments()
    .subscribe(
        {
          apartments.clear()
          apartments.addAll(it)
          view.showApartments(apartments)
        },
        { println(it.message) }
    )
```

This call works on Postman and the result is the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "591ecaca861a528a5b4c3d90",
    "id": "ROC 03"
  },
  {
    "_id": "591a0fb2861a528a5b4c3d60"
  },
  {
    "_id": "58be94d484c4b0a468fb93e0",
    "id": "CAN 2.3",
    "address": "Els Refugis"
  }
]
```

Comment: just try first to consume the endpoint without return single. Not sure your problem is related with RX

Comment: It seems it's not, when executing the synchronous call wth retrofit via .execute() it also freezes with the black screen. Maybe it's the way i'm using this URL query?

Comment: Not familiarize with android mate. Just try to make a very simple request to the endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are making web call in main thread. It is strange, that you just get something like ANR and not android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

```
getAllApartmentsUseCase
    .getAllApartments()

    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  //scheduler in which observable will execute
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //scheduler in which subscriber's methods will be called

    .subscribe(/*subscriber*/)
```

https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a